# SQL Server 2008 R2 hemisphere limitation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, geospatial

Does any one know if the limitaition on SQL Server 2008 that a geography cannot be larger than a hemisphere (described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/isaac/archive/2009/02/06/the-geography-hemisphere-limitation.aspx)) has been fixed/relaxed in 2008 R2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote Isaac Kunen (the same you linked the article to) in [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlspatial/thread/256f0ada-bf29-4f7e-8cab-570b17bd0753) posting regarding a question about "Spatial Changes in SQL Server 2008 R2":

> Not in R2.  From the core engine perspective, the R2 release is pretty minimal: most of the changes are in the BI stack.  We added support for >64 processors, but I think that may be it.  The spatial team is targeting the next major release for additional functionality.

So the answer looks like: "No changes."